# Pandas merge_asof tolerance must be integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched around, but could not find the answer I was looking for.  I have two dataframes, one has fairly discrete integer values in column A (df2) the other does not (df1).  I would like to merge the two such that where column A is within 1, values in columns C and D would get merged once and NaN otherwise.

```
df1=
         A             B
0      30.00      -52.382420
1      33.14      -50.392513
2      36.28      -53.699646
3      39.42      -49.228439
..      ...            ...
497   1590.58     -77.646561
498   1593.72     -77.049423
499   1596.86     -77.711639
500   1600.00     -78.092979

df2=
         A             C           D
0      0.009          NaN         NaN                     
1      0.036          NaN         NaN
2      0.100          NaN         NaN 
3     10.000         12.4        0.29 
4     30.000         12.82       0.307 
..       ...          ...         ...
315   15000.000        NaN        7.65
316   16000.000        NaN        7.72
317   17000.000        NaN        8.36
318   18000.000        NaN        8.35
```

I would like the output to be

```
merged=
         A             B            C             D
0      30.00      -52.382420      12.82         0.29
1      33.14      -50.392513       NaN           NaN
2      36.28      -53.699646       NaN           NaN
3      39.42      -49.228439       NaN           NaN
..       ...          ...          ...           ...
497    1590.58    -77.646561       NaN           NaN
498    1593.72    -77.049423       NaN           NaN
499    1596.86    -77.711639       NaN           NaN
500    1600.00    -78.092979      28.51          2.5
```

I tried:

```
merged = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='A', tolerance=1, direction='nearest')
```

Which gives me a MergeError: key must be integer or timestamp.

So far the only way I've been able to successfully merge the dataframes is with:

```
merged = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='A')
```

But this takes whatever value was close enough in columns C and D and fills in the NaN values.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing a similar problem, the column that the merge is performed on must be an integer.  In my case this meant having to change column A to an int.

```
df1['A Int'] = df1['A'].astype(int)
df2['A Int'] = df2['A'].astype(int)

merged = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='A Int', direction='nearest', tolerance=1)
```